# How do i find the integral of the movmean function on the top graph

Tags: matlab

[How do i find the integral of the movmean function on the top graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppatQ.png)
The intz doesnt work, and im not so sure what the trap gives me:

```
subplot(3,1,1);
Fz1=detrend(Fz(500:1200000));
plot(Fz1,'Color','k');
hold on
M1 = movmean(Fz(500:1200000),[2000,2000]);
M11=detrend(M1);
plot(M11,'Color','r')
trapz(M11)
intz = int(M11)
```

this line `intz = int(M11)`throwing an exception. Please tell me what is wrong on here

Comment: Although you have a clear question, your example is not really reproducible, please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: So what is the output to your call `trapz(M11)`, have you read [the help of trapz](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) or have you taken a look on the examples? What are you expecting `int(M11)` to do?

Comment: please correct your image url

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing your commands. The `trapz` is the command that is doing the integration using the trapezoidal integration method. The command `int` does not do integration; it creates variables of integer type given integer-valued floating-point (a.k.a. double) variables.

Most likely you are seeing this kind of error

```
M11 = [1.2 3.4]; % as an example
int(M11)

Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

because your data in `M11` contains non-integer values. In short `int` is not necessary for integration; just use `trapz`. See `help trapz` in MATLAB for details on using this command.